# How to fix Field_Integrity_Exception

Tags: developer-console

In my dev console for 3 days now Iam getting these Error I tried to log out and relogin closed the class and VF page and tried still Iam showing this error.

Whenever i make any changes to class of VF I get this error.

After my class of VF page wont get saved it will show only Saving... for more than 6-7 hrs.

please see the screen shot below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue. Check [Developer console cannot save classes/triggers/pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204953&language=en_US)

- Create a new Developer Console workspace.
- From the Developer Console, select Workspace > New Workspace.
- Enter a name for your new workspace
  and then click OK. Delete your corrupted workspace:

  1. From theDeveloper Console, select Workspace > Workspace Manager.
  2. Highlight your corrupted workspace.
  3. Click Delete.

Comment: ,I tried to delete the old workspace, But it shows me unable to delete

Comment: First, create the new Workspace  and then try to delete the older one.